# how to upload image to server include original and resize image?

Tags: android, bitmap

how to upload image to server include original and resize image?

this is my code

```
private String convertToString()
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] imgByte = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

I hope can upload original image and resize image(like width:80 height:80)

so how can I do?

this is my ApiInterface code

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("https://example.com/upload.php")
    Call<UploadProfile> uploadProfile(@Field("image") String image, @Field("userID") String userID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use retrofit component and pass files in array via Multipart post request

```
@Multipart
@POST("your_host/upload")
Call<ApiResponse> uploadFiles(@Part MultipartBody.Part[] files);
```

Comment: so this is my code, Call<UploadProfile> uploadProfile(@Field("image") String image, @Field("userID") String userID);.  I need to add @Part MultipartBody.Part[] files?

Comment: Yes and pass images via this param not "image" param you have. Read about sending files via multipart

Comment: here is a link to article https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: but, I just want to choose one image, and when user upload the image can auto spilt two files ( one original file one resize small file)